# Непрерывный период дат sql

Tags: sql, oracle, дата

Как преобразовать периоды, если дата начала события и дата конца одинаковая? Если различается хотя бы на 1 день, то считать как разные периоды события.

На вход есть данные:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-10-02 | 2012-11-15 |
| 1 | 2012-11-15 | 2012-12-24 |
| 1 | 2012-12-24 | 2013-01-01 |
| 2 | 2009-11-02 | 2011-03-04 |
| 2 | 2011-03-04 | 2021-06-29 |
| 2 | 2021-09-30 | 2021-10-05 |
| 2 | 2021-10-06 | 2021-10-13 |

**Ожидаемый результат:**

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-10-02 | 2013-01-01 |
| 2 | 2009-11-02 | 2021-06-29 |
| 2 | 2021-09-30 | 2021-10-05 |
| 2 | 2021-10-06 | 2021-10-13 |

Ранее находил похожие вопросы, но там подход совершенно другой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT id, start_date AS a_date, 1 AS weight FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, end_date, -1 FROM test
  ),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT id, a_date, SUM(weight) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY a_date) weight
  FROM cte1
  ),
cte3 AS (
  SELECT id, a_date, SUM(CASE WHEN weight = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY a_date DESC) group_no
  FROM cte2
  )
SELECT id, MIN(a_date) start_date, MAX(a_date) end_date
FROM cte3
GROUP BY id, group_no;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/63oH2CY7